# Delete Highlighted Cell in Jtable

Tags: jtable, selection, highlight, cells

I would like to ask if there is a way to delete more than 1 cell in a JTable (column-wise) using delete button. I can already delete a cell using the delete button however, when I try to highlight cells and delete it, it only deletes 1 cell not the whole highlighted cells.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out and thought to share how I did it for future reference. If there is anyone there that can simplify the below codes, please do so because I know I don't write codes that clean. lol

```
public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent evt){ 
int[] row = tblList.getSelectedRows();
int[] col = tblList.getSelectedColumns();
for (int i =0;i<tblList.getSelectedRowCount();i++){
for (int j = 0;j<tblList.getSelectedColumnCount();j++){
int rows = tblList.convertRowIndexToModel(row[i]);
int cols = tblList.convertColumnIndexToModel(col[j]);
tblList.getModel().setValueAt("", rows, cols);
}
}
}
```